# Delete a node Binary Search tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I currently have an issue understanding how to delete a node from a binary search tree when I'm NOT being passed a node. I have 2 classes, BSTSet and BSTNode, each have a remove method..

```
public class BSTSet <E extends Comparable<E>> extends AbstractSet <E> {

  // the root of the supporting binary search tree
  private BSTNode<E> root;

  // number of elements in the set
  private int count = 0;


  public boolean remove(E item) {
     if(root == null) return false;
     else return root.remove(item);
  }
}


 public class BSTNode <E extends Comparable<E>> {

   private E value;
   private BSTNode<E> left;
   public BSTNode<E> right;

   public BSTNode<E>remove(E item) {
      //The code i'm confused about
   }

 }
```

I understand the removal method when I'm being passed a node but I don't know where to start when i'm calling the remove method on the root and trying to remove the node from the Node class. Can someone please enlighten me? Thanks. If you would like anymore information please ask.

Answer (score 0):

I get the vibe this is for a school assignment (since the use of a binary search tree is almost non-existent post school), so I will explain but I wont be including any code.

When you remove an element from a tree you want to have some promotion happen from the BSTNode.right. the right child of the node you are removing is the node that will take the place of the removed node. You havent included code about adding, but im making the assumption that the right is greater than the root node, and the left is less than the root node. This means that if you remove the current node, you want to promote the next closest node, which is the right.

Now, you have a problem. If the current_node.right has a left node of it a own, then you will have two left nodes,  potentially. You will want to move the current_node.right.left in the place of current_node.left.right. Then this problem repeats recursively through the rest of the tree, so you will want to adjust accordingly. Just make sure you dont lose nodes further towards the leaves because you are replacing nodes without handling the children.

If something was unclear,  or you have other questions, please let me know. As i said, I dont mind helping you, but I think everyone can agree we dont want to write your assignment for you, so I wont be including code specific to this problem that solves it for you...sorry :/